# Pulling Data For A List Of URLs Using The Google Analytics Sheets Add-On

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've been looking into The Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on, however, currently, it pulls the data for the entire account, I want to pull the data only for specific URLs (new blog posts uploaded which will be updated once a month).

I understand I could use something like "ga:pagePath=~^/blog/" however, this would only show the total number of sessions for the "/blog/" section and not for individual posts, ideally, I want the format to be like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvc6M.png)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to work around this manually to aggregate the correct data.

When it comes to seperate posts/pages, use this:
"ga:pagePath=@YourURL" =@ means contains substring.

IF blogs follow naming conventions, you can filter the different levels of pagepaths, using =@, till you find the correct URL.

I always practice building these out before in Google UA Query Builder.

https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/query-explorer/

Here's a screenshot of what I tested to find the results:
[Dimensions + Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzPrR.png)